# Import .csv to create a list of filenames and corresponding owners

Tags: powershell, csv, filenames, file-ownership

I am working on creating a script that will read a .csv document containing a single column of filenames (one per cell) and search a larger folder for each of the files matching the filenames provided and identify the 'owner' using:

```
(get-acl $file).owner
```

Currently I have several bits of code that can do individual parts, but I am having a hard time tying it all together. Ideally, a user can simply input file names into the .csv file, then run the script to output a second .csv or .txt identifying each file name and it's owner.

csv formatting will appear as below (ASINs is header):

```
ASINs
B01M8N1D83.MAIN.PC_410
B01M14G0JV.MAIN.PC_410
```

Pull file names without header:

```
$images = Get-Content \\path\ASINs.csv | Select -skip 1
```

Find images in larger folder to pull full filename/path (not working):

```
ForEach($image in $images) {

    $images.FullName | ForEach-Object

       {
       $ASIN | Get-ChildItem -Path $serverPath -Filter *.jpg -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | Set-Content \\path\FullNames.csv
       }
}
```

At that point I would like to use the full file paths provided by FullNames.csv to pull the owners from the files in their native location using the above mentioned:

```
(get-acl $file).owner
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to tie these together into one fluid script?

**EDIT**
I was able to get the following to work without the loop, reading one of the filenames, but I need it to loop as there are multiple filenames.

New CSV Format:

```
    BaseName
    B01LVVLSCM.MAIN.PC_410
    B01LVY65AN.MAIN.PC_410
    B01MAXORH6.MAIN.PC_410
    B01MTGEMEE.MAIN.PC_410
```

New Script:

```
$desktopPath = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath([System.Environment+SpecialFolder]::Desktop)
$images = $desktopPath + '\Get_Owner'
Get-ChildItem -Path $images | Select BaseName | Export-Csv $desktopPath`\Filenames.csv -NoTypeInformation
$serverPath = 'C:\Users\tuggleg\Desktop\Archive'
$files = Import-Csv -Path $desktopPath`\Filenames.csv
While($true) {
ForEach ($fileName in $files.BaseName)
{
Get-ChildItem -Path $serverPath -Filter "*$fileName*" -Recurse -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue' |
        Select-Object -Property @{
            Name='Owner'
            Expression={(Get-Acl -Path $_.FullName).Owner}
          },'*' |
        Export-Csv -Path $desktopPath`\Owners.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
}
```

Any ideas on the loop issue? Thanks everyone!

Comment: Can you provide the parts you're trying to combine?  Alongside a sample of the csv (just a few lines would be sufficient)

Comment: Add it to your question with formatting, please.

Comment: added additional info as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example assumes your csv contains partial filenames.  It will search the filepath and filter for those partials.

Example.csv

```
"ASINs"
"B01M8N1D83.MAIN.PC_410"
"B01M14G0JV.MAIN.PC_410"
```

Code.ps1

```
$Files = Import-Csv -Path '.\Example.csv'

ForEach ($FileName in $Files.ASINs)
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path $serverPath -Filter "*$FileName*" -Recurse -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue' |
        Select-Object -Property @{
            Name='Owner'
            Expression={(Get-Acl -Path $_.FullName).Owner}
          },'*' |
        Export-Csv -Path '\\path\FullNames.csv' -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: Don't forget about retrieving and outputting the file owner data.

Comment: @codemaker Thanks for the reminder.  I've updated the example.

Comment: This is a great start, i should be able to modify this and get exactly what we need! Thanks so much @TheIncorrigible1